# Retrieving back-dated RSS articles

Tags: api, rss, aggregation, legacy

I was wondering if any of the big news agencies (CNN, Time, Huffington Post, New York Times, etc) have any method of retrieving older articles via RSS feeds, or another method of retrieving them in a way that can be parsed for aggregation?

I know about archive.org's API, though that seems to have large gaps in data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Services like Feedly store feed history. See the API: https://developer.feedly.com/v3/streams/